# How to use a Directive on a Query argument in ChilliCream GraphQL

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

**Scenario**

I am using .NET Core 6 and [ChilliCream v12](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate) I want to use a custom Directive on certain arguments of queries and mutations.

I have been able to get Directives to work on fields of a Type but not on an argument of a Query/Mutation.

[Here](https://github.com/chris7818kbbf4/HotchocolateExample.git) is a repo I made with a simple example.

This query below should show the directive working on the UserType's `Name` field but not on the userByEmail query's `email` argument:

```
query{
  userByEmail(email: "test") {
    id
    name
    email
  }
}
```